# Elasticsearch - add custom field / type to document

Tags: elasticsearch

to create a bidirectional sync from elasticsearch to an (older) database i need an additional information for each document in elasticsearch.

Therefore i would like to add an extra type / field in the meta information like this "_anotherType":

```
{
    "_index" : "elastic",
    "_type" : "mytype",
    "_anotherType" : "justanothertype",
    "_id" : "AVdmHHg7S9-Jgvd36DT2",
    "_score" : 0.53454715,
    "_source" : {
        "consignee" : "Jackie Chan",
        "consignor" : "John Doe",
        "revenue" : "123456",
        "timestamp" : "1970-01-01 00:00:01"
    }
}
```

But how can i add an information like this to each document?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Why can't you just use a normal field within the `_source` of the document?

Comment: We use the whole *_source* for the frontend where it is shown and mapped automatically. If we can't find an other solution this will be a opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not possible. What is possible though is to introduce the `_meta` meta field

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Custom-metadata-per-index-td4018660.html